# How can I make this program to execute so that the user can't enter a value that already exists in the array

Tags: c++

How can I make this program to execute so that the user can't enter a value that already exists in the array.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number[15], i, num;

    cout << "Enter 15 different integer numbers"
         << "\n";

    //input of the value
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        cout << "input value " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> num;
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                if (num == number[i]) {
                    cout << "The number already exists!"
                         << "\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot prevent the user to enter data. The approach is to check the data and discard it if you like, then prompt the user again.

Comment: Use an (unordered) *set* instead of an array. Insert numbers while the size is less than `15` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this out but you should use 'do while' so the user will be forced to enter the right number if not the loop is gonna repeat until the number is correct.  **sorry if doesn't work or show an error**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number[15], num;
    int i = 0;
  
    cout << "Enter 15 different integer numbers"
         << "\n";
 do{
     cout << "input value " << i + 1 << " : ";
     cin >> num;
        if (num == number[i]) {
             cout << "The number already exists!"
             << "\n";
         }
       else{
          i++;
         }
     }
    while(i < 15 && num != number[i]);
   
    return 0;
}
```